# Resolving interface with generic type using Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I am trying to resolve a concrete type using the interface with a generic type that it inherits from.

It all seems to work, but when I try and call a method on the resolved concrete type it throws an exception of:

> {"The best overloaded method match for
>   'MvcApplication2.Utilities.Common.CQRS.GetAlbumsByIdQueryHandler.Execute(MvcApplication2.Utilities.Common.CQRS.GetAlbumsByIdQuery)'
>   has some invalid arguments"}

Does anyone know what could be causing this? The types that resolved are correct, I think it might have something to do with the use of the dynamic type?

Thanks.

---

Here is my installer for the handlers:

```
container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<IQueryHandler>()
                                        .BasedOn(typeof (IQueryHandler<>))
                                        .WithService
                                        .AllInterfaces()
                                        .LifestyleSingleton());
```

And the resolution is currently:

```
        Type queryHandlerType = typeof (IQueryHandler<>).MakeGenericType(query.GetType());
        dynamic queryHandler = _kernal.Resolve(queryHandlerType);

        return queryHandler.Handle(query);
```

And the relevant classes:

```
public interface IQueryHandler<in TQuery> : IQueryHandler where TQuery : IQuery
{
    IQueryResult Handle(TQuery query);
}


public class GetAlbumsByIdQueryHandler : IQueryHandler<GetAlbumsByIdQuery>
{
    #region IQueryHandler<GetAlbumsByIdQuery> Members

    public IQueryResult Execute(GetAlbumsByIdQuery query)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  return queryHandler.Handle((dynamic)query);
```